# jquery ui drag & drop effect

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

In one panel I have the called resource,like a yellow square

I want drag the element to the another panel,and copy one,but the original one still there,

the markup is simple:

```
   <div id="panel">
        <div id="square" class="square"></div>  //the resource
    </div>
    <div id="canvas">
    </div>
```

the drag js code:

```
$('#panel .square').draggable({
    appendTo: "#canvas",
    helper: "clone"
});

$('#canvas').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var $temp_id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        var $new_id = $temp_id + "_01";
        $(ui.draggable).clone()
                        .css({ 'top': ui.offset.top, 'left': ui.offset.left })
                        .appendTo($(this))
                        .attr('id', $new_id);

        $('#'+$new_id+'').draggable();
    }
});
```

I want only the resource element could copy itself,but the copy one in the canvas could copy themself,too!Inherit the copy ablity!

Thank you

here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9kdjQ/)

What I have done ?Why this could happened?How can I cancel this?

Comment: Have you thought about doing something like removing .square from the cloned element? something like .attr('id', $new_id).attr('class', 'square-no-drag'); ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your drop event.

```
ui.draggable.remove();
```

That would remove the original element.

also to prevent the duplication of your items, consider adding this to your draggable.

```
accept: function(d) {
        return $(this).find(d).length == 0
}
```

What it does  is; it checks your container for the prescence of object `d`, if that object is present, the code would `return false` therefore preventing the drop of the object which causes the duplication.

Hope this helps.